# Web service to see postgis polygons

Tags: postgis, polygon, web-service, web

Is there any website or web service where I throw a polygon postgis and he show me on the map this polygon.

Example:

I put this

```
POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))
```

and the service show me the polygon on a map?

I don't want to create a full application, only want see the polygons that the Mondrian/Pentaho give me and I'd like to see the polygon on a map. If exists some plugin to pentaho that do this, would be perfect.

Comment: In fact, the Mondrian returns me a GMX query and I have the possibility to view the geom columns, so, I would like to copy this geom data and paste and some place to view it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my understanding of the question, is totally different from other people who have answered, but I think that you have a bunch of polygons in WKT, and you want to see them on a map, as a one time thing.

If so, I'll guide you to this sample of OpenLayers: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

You can paste the WKT in the Box, and select Well Known Text as the format. Then Just press 'add feature'. You will see the geometry on the map.

Comment: Ahh yeah seems I misread the question :)

Comment: @NathanW I don't think you are to blame. The question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

[postgisonline](http://postgisonline.org) is for things like this.

go to http://postgisonline.org/map.php and paste your code.
But you have to write it as a query understandable for PostGIS and call the geometry the_geom.
Then you will, from your example get this in return

[image]

Comment: Interesting link. But I could not figure out how to get the query to run.

Comment: press "Map 1", you can also press the number"2" button to get a quick tour, how to use the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a new "webservice" called [MapFart](http://mapfart.com/) :)

```
alias mapfart='curl -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @- mapfart.com/api/fart'
echo 'LINESTRING(3 4,10 50,20 25)' | mapfart
```

Answer (score 0):

To set up a web service, try this: http://mapserver.org/trunk/tinyows/ and then use openlayers to view it.

Or you could use QGIS to connect to postGIS and view the data.

Or try this: http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/demos/postgis-restful-web-service-framework/ which I don't really understand, but seems to use PHP to get vectors for leaflet.

In fact, that last one looks like the easiest. See:

- http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/documentation/#docs-prwsf
- https://github.com/tobinbradley/dirt-simple-postgis-http-api